# How to test a wrapped anonymous function with mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, middleware, chai

i'am new in the JS world and mocha framework.
I would like to write a unite test in order to cover this middleware module.

Here is the code of my middleware module:

```
exports.authorizeStrategy = (roles = []) => {
  // roles param can be a single role string (e.g. Role.User or 'User')
  // or an array of roles (e.g. [Role.Admin, Role.User] or ['Admin', 'User'])
  if (typeof roles === 'string') {
    roles = [roles];
  }
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (roles.length && !roles.includes(req.USER.role)) {
      // user's role is not authorized
      return res.status(403).json({message: 'Unauthorized'});
    } else {
      // authorization successful
      next();
    }
  };
};
```

a wrote this test so far:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const authenticationMiddleWare = require('../../middleware/authenticate');
const authorizeMiddleware = require('../../middleware/authorize');

describe('Authorize Middleware Tests', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.JwtStrategy = sinon.stub(
        authenticationMiddleWare, 'JwtStrategy',
    ).callsFake((req, res, next) => {
      req.USER = {id: 1, role: 'admin'};
      next();
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.JwtStrategy.restore();
  });

  it('Should Authorize A User With The Right Role', function() {
    const res = authorizeMiddleware.authorizeStrategy('admin');
    /*res is a function but how to test it (call + validation)?*/
  });
});
```

but a to execute and test the anonymous returned function ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create mocks for `req`, `res`, and `next`. Execute the `authorizeStrategy` function and pass these mocks to the returned function.

`authorize.js`:

```js
exports.authorizeStrategy = (roles = []) => {
  if (typeof roles === 'string') {
    roles = [roles];
  }
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (roles.length && !roles.includes(req.USER.role)) {
      return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
};
```

`authorize.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const authorizeMiddleware = require('./authorize');

describe('Authorize Middleware Tests', function () {
  it('Should return unauthorized message when A User With The wrong Role', function () {
    const req = {
      USER: { id: 1, role: 'guest' },
    };
    const res = {
      status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      json: sinon.stub(),
    };
    authorizeMiddleware.authorizeStrategy(['admin'])(req, res);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.status, 403);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.json, { message: 'Unauthorized' });
  });

  it('Should Authorize A User With The Right Role', function () {
    const req = {
      USER: { id: 1, role: 'admin' },
    };
    const res = {};
    const next = sinon.stub();
    authorizeMiddleware.authorizeStrategy(['admin'])(req, res, next);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(next);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  Authorize Middleware Tests
    ✓ Should return unauthorized message when A User With The wrong Role
    ✓ Should Authorize A User With The Right Role


  2 passing (6ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |   85.71 |    71.43 |     100 |   85.71 |                   
 authorize.js |   85.71 |    71.43 |     100 |   85.71 | 3                 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```